# "Smooth and Regular" scroll in flash

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, gsap

I am working on a news ticker in Flash AS3. The code is reading some RSS from CNN and generates a MovieClip with headline text one after another. Now this movieclip starts scrolling from right to left. For scrolling I am using TweenLite. I don't want any easing, just want a regular and smooth scrolling.

I have used both options:

```
TweenLite.to(news_mc, 60, {x:minX} );
```

and

```
TweenLite.to(news_mc, 60, {x:minX, ease:Linear.easeNone} );
```

But, in both case, the animation is not smooth. It starts scrolling speedily and at last it becomes very slow.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen something similar to this. Are you implementing your TweenLite call in a loop? You should only be calling for a tween on the target object once. Only once that tween is finished  or you want a brand new tween on that object should you call TweenLite.to with that target object again.

Seeing as how you're only after a linear tween, would it not be simpler to simply increment/decrement the target's X every frame? Something like this:

```
this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnterFrame)

private function onEnterFrame(e:Event):void
{
    if(news_mc.x > minX)
    {
        news_mc.x -= 3 //This is a shot in the dark, tweak this for your values
    }
    else
    {
        news_mc.x = maxX
    }
}
```

Comment: After more testing I realized that other tween on screen are making the ticker's animation slow and slow. There are two more sections on the screen "advert" and "some list" that are using TweenLite with Cubic.EaseOut. Whenever the advert section loads a new image with fade-in it slows down the ticker a bit. After 10-12 change of advert the ticker goes really dead slow. Though, for each advert change, I am using imgLoader.unloadAndStop() to free the memory. Any idea?

Comment: It still sounds like your applying multiple tweens to the ticker. Post up some code in your question so we can see exactly what's going on